# How can I Create a Relationship b/n Columns & Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, relationship, tabular

Currently my index page is formatted like this picture:

[image]

But I'd like the page to look like this:

[image]

How can I create this relationship where when the _form outputs **name** | **metric** | **result** | **date** that it creates a new row of result & date if their is already a preexisting name & metric in the system?

From what I read this seems like a daunting task so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should try to write some code on your own, then post your code for help if you're stuck.

Comment: I tried googling but idk where to go from here or where to start

Comment: Seems easy, you just make a table and populate it with a bunch of strings `"Result"` unless the column is the last one, in which case you write `"Date"`. Kidding aside, you need to do a bit better description of your requirements. For instance, what happens if a metric doesn't have a result on a given date? What happens if it has several? A different number than another metric? What happens if a date doesn't have any results at all? Real or real-looking data is way more useful than just a static placeholder; the latter hides design complexity.